# Lag Based on Specified Order in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, sqlhelper, mysql-helper

Does anyone know of a way to LAG in a specified order? In the example below, I provide a table with my current output [Lag (Current)] and my desired output [Lag (Desired)] columns. I am interested in creating a lag for the event time based on event time order, need to make sure that the Groups do not get out of order. The issue is that Group CL1 is currently not being lagged based on time, its based on the group, so that is where I am struggling.

| Personal ID | Event Time | Groups | Lag (Current) | Lag (Desired) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99999999 | 4:18:58 PM | GM1 |  |  |
| 99999999 | 4:21:03 PM | GM1 | 4:18:58 PM | 4:18:58 PM |
| 99999999 | 4:21:42 PM | CL1 |  |  |
| 99999999 | 4:25:04 PM | CL1 | 4:21:42 PM | 4:21:42 PM |
| 99999999 | 4:25:40 PM | GM2 |  |  |
| 99999999 | 4:25:45 PM | GM2 | 4:25:40 PM | 4:25:40 PM |
| 99999999 | 4:26:14 PM | CL1 | 4:25:04 PM |  |
| 99999999 | 4:26:23 PM | CL1 | 4:21:42 PM | 4:21:42 PM |

Here is the SQL I have tried.

`SELECT LAG() OVER (PARTITION BY Personal ID, Groups ORDER BY Personal ID, Event Time)`

##### Updated

**Second example**

> The below seemed to work, but not sure if its correct, especially as more data passes through. It did work for this example and the one you provided above, I just added the groups in the the last w2.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'CL1' groups UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'FZ1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '8:13:42 AM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '8:13:42 AM' event_time, 'GM2' 
)
```

**Expected Output**
[image]

Comment: `Lag` in last row should be `4:26:14 PM`, not `4:21:42 PM` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below *gaps and islands* approach.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:18:58 PM' event_time, 'GM1' groups UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:21:03 PM' event_time, 'GM1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:21:42 PM' event_time, 'CL1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:25:04 PM' event_time, 'CL1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:25:40 PM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:25:45 PM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:26:14 PM' event_time, 'CL1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '4:26:23 PM' event_time, 'CL1' 
)
SELECT personal_id, event_time, groups, LAG(event_time) OVER w2 AS lag FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER w1 - SUM(IF(flag, 1, 0)) OVER w1 AS part FROM (
    SELECT *, groups = LAG(groups) OVER w0 AS flag 
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY personal_id ORDER BY event_time)
  ) t WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY personal_id ORDER BY event_time)
) t WINDOW w2 AS (PARTITION BY personal_id, part ORDER BY event_time);
```

**Query results**

[image]

##### Updated

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'CL1' groups UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'FZ1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '8:13:42 AM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '8:13:43 AM' event_time, 'GM2'
)
SELECT personal_id, event_time, groups, LAG(event_time) OVER w2 AS lag FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER w1 - SUM(IF(flag, 1, 0)) OVER w1 AS part FROM (
    SELECT *, groups = LAG(groups) OVER w0 AS flag 
      FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personal_id, event_time) AS rn FROM sample_table) t
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY personal_id ORDER BY event_time, rn)
  ) t WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY personal_id ORDER BY event_time, rn)
) t WINDOW w2 AS (PARTITION BY personal_id, part ORDER BY event_time, rn);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was impressive. Exactly what I needed and I learned something new. Thank you!

Comment: SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'CL1' groups UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '1:04:12 AM' event_time, 'FZ1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '8:13:42 AM' event_time, 'GM2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '99999999' personal_id, '8:13:42 AM' event_time, 'GM2'

Comment: Looks like this example does not work. Any way to fix it?

Comment: @leaner007, would you share the expected outoupt as well ? and one thing that I'd like to check is your last 2 rows has same `event_time`. is it correct ? (in case that, we can't apply `LAG` function)

Comment: I have added the below.

Comment: @leaner007, you can remove your *answer* ;o). I've moved it to your question. And for the sample in your expected output, the current query will works. But for the sample in your query, it becomes different problem.   Would you confirm that same *personal_id* and *groups*  can have same *event_time* or not ?  I'll get back to you later in my free time with more explanation based on your response.

Comment: sorry, not for same *personal_id* and *groups*, just for *personal_id* can it have same *event_time* or not ?

Comment: yes, one ID can have the same time stamp for different groups. The only reason why there are different timestamps in the output expected is because I could not replicate the expected output in SQL. So, the example I have provided does have the same time stamp.

Comment: kindly check the below link and updated answer as well.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PpZDLSmkGRKjtrZMGiunKhcKPHhkbXLePC1HAoyZ3c8/edit?usp=sharing